# Adding String at specific postition of a delimiter for hundred thousand lines

Tags: linux, awk

One text file:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;@;
17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;@;
etc..
```

Want to add '/c_h/' to every column 15

Want the results to be:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;/c_h/15;16;@;
17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;/c_h/31;32;@;
etc..
```

I was using awk but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
awk -v FS=";" -v OFS=";" ' { $15 = "/c_h/"$15 ; print $0 } ' file.txt
```

First of all, you need to set your input field separator and output field separator to be ";" in this case. Then just modify the field you want.

Comment: Thank you, this was well explained

Comment: This could could be shorten some to: `awk -F\; -vOFS=\; '{$15="/c_h/"$15}1' file` @steph To edit same file `awk -F\; -vOFS=\; '{$15="/c_h/"$15}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -r -e 's/(([0-9]+;){14})/\1\/c_h\//' YourFileName
```

To do it inline

```
 sed -r -e 's/(([0-9]+;){14})/\1\/c_h\//' -i.bak YourFileName
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind trying sed, how would I get it to edit the same file?

Comment: This will fail if one column does contain other info than number, or number with `.` like `5.8`